# Using IF statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to use an IF ELSE statement in a sql query because I want to sum the units per district based on their package size per each PLN #. Can I do this? Here is my attempt, which does not work:

```
      SELECT district_nbr,PLN_NBR, SUM(A.LO_IOH_UNITS) AS TOTAL_UNITS, SUM (A.LO_IOH_EXT_COST_DLRS) AS TOTAL_DOLLARS
FROM FCT_LOIOH_DAY_STR_PLN A, DIM_PROD_PLN B, DIM_LOCATION C
WHERE B.PLN_NBR IN(40000683181, 40000418723, 40000335776)
AND A.PROD_ID = B.PROD_ID
AND A.LOC_ID = C.LOC_ID
if PLN_NBR = '40000683181' then SUM(A.LO_IOH_UNITS)/25
else SUM(A.LO_IOH_UNITS)/60

GROUP BY district_nbr,PLN_NBR
```

Comment: You can't use an `IF` statement in SQL, only in PL/SQL.  You can use a `CASE` statement in SQL.  But I can't figure out what your `IF` statement is trying to do in your `WHERE` clause.  Do you want to compare those sums to something?  Do you want to `SELECT` them?  Something else?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I'm not trying to compare anything. I want any PLN # that =40000683181 to then have the sum of the units divide by 25, any other PLN# not equal to the latter should have the sum of units divided by 60...can I do this with a case? If so, how ?

Comment: So, you want this calculation in the `SELECT` list?  Not in the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT district_nbr, PLN_NBR, 
       SUM(A.LO_IOH_UNITS) / (case when PLN_NBR = 40000683181 then 25 else 60 end) AS TOTAL_UNITS, 
       SUM (A.LO_IOH_EXT_COST_DLRS) AS TOTAL_DOLLARS
FROM FCT_LOIOH_DAY_STR_PLN A, 
     DIM_PROD_PLN B, 
     DIM_LOCATION C
WHERE B.PLN_NBR IN (40000683181, 40000418723, 40000335776)
  AND A.PROD_ID = B.PROD_ID
  AND A.LOC_ID = C.LOC_ID  
GROUP BY district_nbr, PLN_NBR;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL, you can use `CASE WHEN ... ELSE` for conditionals:

```
CASE WHEN PLN_NBR = '40000683181' THEN SUM(A.LO_IOH_UNITS) / 25
                                  ELSE SUM)A.LO_IOH_UNITS) / 60 
END
```

Such `CASE WHEN ...` statements go to the part where the other selected columns go:

```
SELECT
  foo,
  bar,
  CASE ....
FROM
   ...
```

Comment: Where would that go with the rest of the select statement? I tried replacing this with the IF I had, but it still says "SQL command not properly ended."